# Tensor product definition in Wikipedia

Tags: tensor-products

In Wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_vector_spaces, tensor product space is explained as the following:

$$F(V\times W) = \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_{(v_i, w_i)} \ \Bigg| \ n\in\mathbb{N}, \alpha_i\in K, (v_i, w_i)\in V\times W \right\}$$

equivalence relation:
\begin{align}
e_{(v_1 + v_2, w)} &\sim e_{(v_1, w)} + e_{(v_2, w)}\\
e_{(v, w_1 + w_2)} &\sim e_{(v, w_1)} + e_{(v, w_2)}\\
ce_{(v, w)} &\sim e_{(cv, w)} \sim e_{(v, cw)}
\end{align}

and $V \otimes W = F(V \times W) / R$

where $R$ is the space created by equivalence relations.

So, the first question is why is free vector space defined as a sum? I cannot get how vector space can be a sum.
Second question is how can we take a quotient space when there is only $e_{(v_i,w_i)}$ and not $e_{(v_i,w_j)}$?

If there is anything I was mistaken, please inform me.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't like "formal sums", let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the set of all functions $V \times W \to K$.  This is a vector space in an obvious way.  Think of $e_{(v,w)}$ as just another name for the function $V \times W \to K$ that maps $(v,w)$ to $1$ and everyhing else to $0$.  The addition and scalar multiplication appearing in the definition of $F(V \times W)$ are now those of $\mathcal{F}$ and $F(V \times W)$ is thus defined as a certain subspace of $\mathcal{F}$.  FWIW, I recommend learning this material from a single textbook (any textbook) and not Wikipedia.

Comment: ^ With the caveat that the functions $V\times W\to K$ are zero at all but finitely many elements of $V\times W$. To go between this functional interpretation and the constructive one, I find it helpful to think of it as a function that sends elements $(v,w)$ to their coefficient in the free vector space. (This is all prior to the quotient process to create the tensor product of course.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The free vector space construction is not just a single sum. Here's an intuitive picture of how I often think of the free vector space construction. We have a set $X$ - note that if this set has any additional structure defined on it, like a binary operation and some axioms, we decide to *forget about it* for the purpose of our construction. So, either naturally or artificially, we will assume that the elements of $X$ are not things that can truly be added together, like $X=\{\rm \square,~dog,~2\}$. Furthermore, we have a field $K$. We then *pretend* we can add things in $X$ together, and multiply them by scalars from $K$, and we end up with formal $K$-linear combinations of the form

$$\sum_{x\in X}\alpha_xx= \alpha_{\square} \square+\alpha_{\rm dog}\mathrm{dog}+\alpha_{2} 2.$$

There is a problem with this though. That numeral "$2$" there is supposed to have no structure to it, as part of our construction process, yet it also designates an element of $K$ too! We don't want to confuse ourselves, so let's put the elements of $X$ as subscripts of a generic "$e$." We then have linear combinations of the form

$$\sum_{x\in X}\alpha_x e_x=\alpha_\square e_\square +\alpha_{\rm dog} e_{\rm dog}+\alpha_2e_2.$$

Keep in mind the $\alpha$ coefficients are scalars from $K$. On top of this, we're well within our rights to now "pretend" that the set of all of these formal sums *satisfies every single vector space axiom*. We have by virtue of imagination created a new vector space out of $X$. (You will notice it is isomorphic to any other vector space of dimension three, or any other free vector space generated by a set of three elements. As I suggested earlier, the actual contents of $X$ are moot, they ultimately play the part of indexing a basis for our space.)

*Remark*. A vector space does not necessarily allow infinite sums. (It can be defined in finite-dimensional vector spaces, or on finite-dimensional subspaces of vector spaces, over a field that is also a complete metric space so that it allows infinite sums in the scalar field. Look up Hilbert or Banach spaces.) Thus in our formal sums, when we write $x\in X$ in the subscript, we run the risk of having an infinite sum if $X$ is itself infinite! To prevent this occurrence, we may instead write

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_{x_{\Large i}} :~~ x_i\in X.$$

These are the actual forms our desired formal combinations will now have.

At this point it gets tricky, because we are going to create the free vector space *out of another vector space* (in fact, out of a Cartesian product of vector spaces). At this point in our discussion, we must completely forget about the fact that $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces and have algebraic structure; temporarily to us they are *just sets* with no further facts about them available for use. As before, we have our set of formal linear combinations:

$$\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_{(v_i,w_i)}: n\in\Bbb N, (v_i,w_i)\in V\times W \right\} $$

*Note*: These $(v_i,w_i)$ are *not* the 2-tuples of basis vectors from $V$ and $W$. They are just a set of $n$ arbitrary vectors from $V\times W$. In fact we have designated no basis for $V$ or $W$. The $v_i$ and $w_i$, for each $i$, can be *any* two elements from $V$ and $W$ respectively.

Now, finally, after all of this, we can remember the vector space structure of $V\times W$ and create the relations given on Wikipedia, and quotient out by them. After the quotient, we can rename the $e_{(v,w)}$ objects (these were the basis vectors when we were still at the stage of a free vector space) as $v\otimes w$. (It gets tedious writing everything in subscripts!)

There are a few very important differences between $V\times W$ and $V\otimes W$ that need to be identified: even though the *pure tensors* $v\otimes w$ have two components, each taken from $V$ and $W$ resp., our tensor product will have sums of pure tensors (so, e.g., $u\otimes v+x\otimes y$) that cannot always be written as pure tensors, because the two components of pure tensors are *independently* linear. For example, in $V\times W$, we can split $(v+x,w+y)$ into $(v,w)+(x,y)$ (you cannot split the first component without also having to split the second), whereas in the tensor product we have to split each individually:

$$\begin{array}{c c c} (v+x)\otimes(w+y) && =v\otimes(w+y) & +x\otimes(w+y) \\ && =v\otimes w +v\otimes y & +x\otimes w+x\otimes y. \end{array}$$

Finally, scalar multiplication of $u\otimes v$ does not affect both componenets at once; only one or the other, resulting in $c(u\otimes v)=(cu)\otimes v=u\otimes(cv)$. In the Cartesian product, scalar multiplication affects both components simultaneously, where $c(u,v)=(cu,cv)$. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

What they mean is that you take the free vector space on $V\times W$. Which means you take an indexed set $\{e_{(v,w)}\}_{(v,w)\in V\times W}$ and you consider all formal (finite) sums $\displaystyle \sum_{(v,w)\in V\times W}\alpha_{(v,w)}e_{(v,w)}$--these are the ELEMENTS of the free vector space, not the vector space itself.

So, if you had the vector space $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3^2$ a typical element of $\mathbb{Z}_3(\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3^2)$ is $2e_{(1,(0,1))}+1e_{(2,(1,2))}$

As for your second question, I could see how that could be slightly confusing. Ignore their notation for a second and look at mine. There is no "dependence" on the indices in the sum, as it sort of appears in their sum (even though really there isn't)--just as there is no "dependence" in the indices of the relation you are quotienting by.

Answer (score 1):

The free vector space is not defined as a sum but rather as a set of sums. Namely, all linear combinations of elements of the basis $\{e_{(v,w)}\}$ with coefficients in $K$.

This is not much different from what you call a linear span, i.e. the vector space you get if you start with a set of vectors. For example, if we are in $\mathbb R^3$, the vector space spanned by $B = \{\left ( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array} \right ),
\left ( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{array} \right ) \}$ is $\mathbb R^2$ and you can denote it by $\{ \sum_{i=1}^2 r_i e_i \mid e_i \in B, r_i \in \mathbb R \}$.

As for your second question: the quotient relation is defined in this way because we want the tensor product to be bilinear. Note that we can define *any* equivalence relation on any set we like. The set we are taking the quotient over in this case is all linear combinations of elements in $\{(v,w) \mid v \in V, w \in W \}$.

Please let me know if this answers your questions, I am not sure I understand your second question and I'm happy to elaborate.