# Definition of the Tensor Product

Tags: linear-algebra

Could anyone explain in basic language what the tensor product is? I am relatively new to matrix algebra and I am completely new to this specific concept. What exactly does it do for me and what properties of it should I know?

Comment: bothered using a search engine? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18881/motivation-for-tensor-product?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138331/tensor-product-definition-in-wikipedia?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144501/what-exactly-is-a-tensor-product?rq=1, and of course any book on advanced linear algebra, or commutative algebra, and also online encyclopedia such as Wikipedia, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tensor product is a gadget which allows you to turn bilinear maps into linear maps between vector spaces. I explain this below.

Let $V,W$ and $X$ be vector spaces. We say a function $f:V \times W \to X$ is *bilinear* if $f(\alpha v_1 + v_2, w) = \alpha f(v_1,w) + f(v_2,w)$ and $f(v, \beta w_1 + w_2) = \beta f(v, w_1) + f(v, w_2)$ for all $v_1, v_2, v \in V$,
$w_1, w_2, w \in W$, $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ (let's work over $\mathbb{R}$). This is just saying that $f$ is linear in each "slot".

Now a tensor product of $V$ and $W$ is a vector space $T$, together with a bilinear map $\otimes$, such that if $f:V \times W \to X$ is bilinear, then there is a unique *linear* map $\varphi: T \to X$ such that $f = \varphi \circ \otimes$,
i.e. $f(x,y) = \varphi(\otimes(x,y)) = \varphi(x \otimes y)$ ($\otimes(x,y)$
is denoted by $x \otimes y$).

Now given vector spaces $V$ and $W$, we can always construct a tensor product[1]. Here is one example:

$\otimes: \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $x \otimes y = x y^t$ ($y^t$ is the transpose) is a bilinear map. One can check (maybe not so easily) that 
the vector space $T$, where $T = \operatorname{span}\{x \otimes y | x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$, is a tensor product of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I suggest you pick up a book on multilinear algebra, which will discuss these things. Or read other things on the internet. Dummit and Foote is also good.

[1] Multilinear Algebra, Werner Greub

[2] Abstract Algebra, Dummit and Foote

Comment: thank you for your help :)

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure how much my response helped. But now when I think about it, Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote have good explanation of the tensor product. I've added this reference to the post.

Comment: If W is a matrix M * N, and x a vector N we know how to compute y="Wx", but what if  W has 3 axes and x 2 axes? What is the general rule of this product generalized to higher dimensions?